# Push new contact to google people api using PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I want to push a new contact entry to google contacts using PHP.

below is my index.php code.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();


$client->setClientId('519334414648-
f2jiml3iuuj87mjn1ofc9kbqmlsn7iqb.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('0x9LpW7Qr37x89YFRtmgq6oH');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://example.com/demo/contacts/redirect.php');

$client->addScope('profile');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');

if (isset($_GET['oauth'])) {
// Start auth flow by redirecting to Google's auth server
$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} 

else if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
// Receive auth code from Google, exchange it for an access token, and
// redirect to your base URL
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/demo/contacts';
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} 

else if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
// You have an access token; use it to call the People API
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$client->setAccessType('online');
// TODO: Use service object to request People data

$client->addScope(Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS);
$service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

$person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();
$person->setPhoneNumbers('1234512345');

$name = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Name();
$name->setDisplayName('test user');
$person->setNames($name);
$exe = $service->people->createContact($person);

} 

else {
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/demo/contacts?oauth';
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I get this error after executing the below code. Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
Can any 1 tell me if my code is correct? if not please suggest the coorect way of pushing the contact to contacts or people API.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php).

The complete step was elaborated in the said documentation, you can follow them to get good results.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php#step_3_set_up_the_sample), the code was also provided,

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'People API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/people.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/people.googleapis.com-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . getenv('HOMEPATH');
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

// Print the names for up to 10 connections.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 10,
  'personFields' => 'names,emailAddresses',
);
$results = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams);

if (count($results->getConnections()) == 0) {
  print "No connections found.\n";
} else {
  print "People:\n";
  foreach ($results->getConnections() as $person) {
    if (count($person->getNames()) == 0) {
      print "No names found for this connection\n";
    } else {
      $names = $person->getNames();
      $name = $names[0];
      printf("%s\n", $name->getDisplayName());
    }
  }
}
```

To create contacts, you can use this [Method: people.createContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact).

> Create a new contact and return the person resource for that contact.

For further reference about OAuth 2.0, you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Also, you can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275526/google-api-error-401-invalid-authentication-credentials) about the remedy of the error if this is applicable to your problem.